# What is the cause of this odd behavior of a shower exhaust fan?

Tags: exhaust-fan, replacement, electric-motor

Recently an old, heavily-used shower exhaust fan started exhibiting a strange behavior.  When the switch was turned off, the RPMs on the fan would die away as normal...but then there would be a pause of a second or two (maybe less), and the fan would spin back up for a second or two.

I wondered if it could be a strange switch issue, but turning the power off at the breaker made the fan exhibit the same behavior.

I swapped it out and the new one works fine. But I'm still curious about what could have caused it. Please be gentle, I know little about single-phase AC motors.

Comment: Damper closing on spin-down would be my guess. Less air actually moved = less load on motor = increased rpm's.

Comment: @kreemoweet That makes a lot of sense. When I took the old fan out, I found that there is indeed a damper.